# SSD crashed with error no boot device fount

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

My 256GB SSD crashed and when I start my laptop I get errors saying no boot device found. On running live cd with boot-repair, I could not fix it.

I had a dual-boot system working fine, until one day, on start up, I got this issue. I had Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

This is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9187103/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the same issue I had on my Vaio SVS with UEFI.

Go to BIOS and set it on Legacy mode, turn off Secure Boot.
Try to boot normaly to GRUB. If not working, boot the Live CD open Gparted Partition Editor. Check your disks and partitions for errors, check where the Windows boot flag is.

Where are you trying to install GRUB? /sda and /sdb?

Week ago I had same problem with RAID0 dual boot and Windows. I could not install Grub on /dev/sda neither on /sdb, so I ran Grub Boot Repair and installed it on the same partition where Ubuntu was. (Volume0...) That fixed the problem with booting Ubuntu.

Try it and report back.

Comment: tried did not worked :(

Comment: Ok, I would suggest trying to boot the system using [SuperGrub2](http://goo.gl/EwFMWn) recovery. It never let me down, booted everything when I had nooby crashes. So check if you can boot, check if the disk is working normaly. Maybe try running GrubRepair from booted OS.EDIT: I too have a 256GB SSD, but I removed my RAID yesterday, now having 2 partitions (64 GB Ubuntu, 64GB Windows 7) and SWAP on sda and whole sdb 128GB for storage. I feel more comfortable knowing RAID0 cannot make any more problems ;)